# Javascript var variable not working as global

Tags: javascript, html, function, var

I have a variable declared as `counts` before the `add_to_download_entries()` function and I am using it later in the `$(document).ready( function () {` function but it always print the value 1 of `count` however when I tested the value of count changes depending on how many checboxes are selected in the `add_to_download_entries` but it's not reflected the same value outside that function in the `$(document).ready( function ()`. Am I using the variables wrong?
[image]

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary boxShadow" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
          Close</button>
        <button id="payment-sub-btn" class="btn btn-success float-right" style="background-color:#28a745!important"
          onclick="update_coupon();">Pay Now $</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Close
        Pay Now $

```js
var selected_lostwill_array = [];

var counts = 1;
var checkboxes;

function add_to_download_entries(data) {
  checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkWills"]:checked');
  counts = checkboxes.length;
  if ($.inArray(data, selected_lostwill_array) >= 0) {
    selected_lostwill_array = $.grep(selected_lostwill_array, function(value) {
      return value != data;
    });
  } else {
    selected_lostwill_array.push(data);
  }
}
// DataTables Functions 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#org_lost_table').DataTable();
  $('#all_lost_table').DataTable();
  if (counts > 0) {
    let finalPrice = Number(counts) * Number(22);
    $("#payment-sub-btn").append(counts);
  } else $("#payment-sub-btn").append(0);
});
```

```html
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkWills" onclick='add_to_download_entries("{{$will->id}}")' />&nbsp;
</td>
```

Comment: The `if` statement only runs once, when the page is first loaded. It doesn't run again when you call `add_to_download_entries()`, so it doesn't see the change to `count`.

Comment: Ah I see. How can I fix it then? is there a way to do it properly? @Barmar

Comment: Put that code in the function.

Comment: It does work but it keep appending the number like 2244 instead of just 44 when only 2 checkboxes are selected. And If I select 3 checkboxes it says 224466. What am I doing wrong?@Barmar

Comment: Because you're appending to `#payment-sub-btn`, not replacing its contents. Use `.text()` instead of `.append()`.

Comment: I updated my code where it is using `pay now $` and appends it after the finalPrice so `pay now $44` for example. If I use `.text` instead of `.append` now I can see `44` but it removes `pay now $` now how can I fix that?

Comment: IMHO: 
* Just don't use global vars
* Maybe a workaround is to try using `counts` like functions parameter/argument
* I'm not sure, but in React, I think `count` should be a state variable

Comment: nevermind. I added the pay now text in front of `.text` so it works now `let finalPrice = "Pay Now $" + Number(counts) * Number(22);` but is it right way to do? @Barmar

Comment: There's no need to write `Number()` around `22`. It's already a number.

Comment: Another way to solve it is to create a span for the number: `Pay now $<span id="paynow"></span>` then use `$("#paynow").text(finalPrice)`